# What sort of design pattern should I be using for a structure that can have different states?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, data-structures, tree

I'm making a program that builds mathematical equations into a tree based on operator precedence, e.g. `x^2+5*x+1` becomes

```
           /       \
          /         \
        x^2+5*x  +   1
       /   \ 
      /     \
    x^2  +  5*x
   / \      / \
  x ^ x    5 * x
```

The data structure I've been using for nodules of the tree is

```
struct node
{
    std::string eq;
    oper op;
    node * LHS;
    node * RHS;
};
```

where `oper` is defined by

```
enum oper { NONE, ADD, SUB, MULT, DIV, EXP };
```

The root node of the tree I drew above could therefore be expressed as

```
{ "x^2+5*x+1", PLUS, ->{ "x^2+5*x", PLUS, ..., ... }, ->{"1", NONE, NULL, NULL} }
```

if that makes sense.

While I'm writing my algorithm to build this tree, I'm realizing that as this tree gets build its nodes have different "states" which are making my code messy and repetitive when trying to deal with the states. For instance, I have a chunks of code that are like

```
        if (rootNode == nullptr)
        {
            rootNode = new node;
            rootNode = thisNode;
        }
        else
        {
            if (rootNode->RHS == nullptr)
            {
                rootNode->RHS = thisNode;
            }
            else
            {
                if (thisNode->op < rootNode->op)
                {
                    node * temp = rootNode;
                    rootNode = thisNode;
                    rootNode->LHS = temp;
                }
                else
                {
                    rootNode->RHS = thisNode;
                }

            }
        }
```

and other stuff where I'm checking whether pointers are `NULL` and trying to determine how much of the `node` has been built and yada-yada. I feel like I should be changing my `node` objects from `struct`s to `class`es and figuring out some way of making things cleaner, with some sort of "state" that a node has, equivalents of "*has a left-hand side and an operator but no right-hand side yet*" and so forth.

Any ideas on how I can exploit C++ to do this?

Comment: Maybe the accepted answer to this can be a starting point, at least? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806760/binary-expression-tree-c

Comment: I would change the structs to classes, use inheritance to model the different types of operators, and encapsulate the different behavior in those classes. During construction I would make sure that the nodes get all their data in the constructor and remain immutable after that, unless you want to manipulate the tree structure later on.

Comment: Not an answer because I'm not sure if this is the right solution for this case, but state can be handled by the [state pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern)

Comment: This question is good but too broad. We don't know which operations you want to perform with the tree and we don't know whether the tree is supposed to be mutable or not. Generally, inheritance does not feel like a good solution here; my gut feeling tells me that you want an STL-style separation into data structure, iterators and algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For evaluating the equations you could use the Interpreter pattern:
https://github.com/iluwatar/java-design-patterns#interpreter

To simplify the code and avoid explicit null checking in your algorithms I would suggest you to try the Null Object pattern:
https://github.com/iluwatar/java-design-patterns#null-object

The examples are in Java but hopefully you get the idea.